# How to stop adding objects given by the user to an arraylist if they already gave it?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, equals, contains

This is the class

```
public class Book {
    private String name;
    private int publicationYear;
    public Book(String name, int publicationYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
    }
    public boolean equals(Book compared) {
        if (this == compared) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(compared instanceof Book)) {
            return false;
        }
        Book comparedBook = (Book) compared;
        if (this.name.equals(comparedBook.name)
                && this.publicationYear == comparedBook.publicationYear) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried doing this in the main

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Name (empty will stop):");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Publication year:");
    int publicationYear = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    Book book = new Book(name, publicationYear);
    if (!(books.contains(book))) {
        books.add(book);
    }
```

So if the user keeps giving a book with the same name and year the program adds them to the list still

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The List is really the wrong tool for the job; a Set is a better way to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t change the signature of [`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

You should use the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html) annotation to catch this kind of error. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) by Oracle.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object compared) {
    if (this == compared) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(compared instanceof Book)) {
        return false;
    }
    Book comparedBook = (Book) compared;
    if (this.name.equals(comparedBook.name)
            && this.publicationYear == comparedBook.publicationYear) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68124051/642706) is correct and wise.

Alternatively, in Java 16+ you could avoid your issue of incorrectly writing the `equals` method by letting Java handle the implementation of `equals`.

## `record`

Java 16 brought the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature. A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably.  You simply declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

And by the way, Java offers a class to represent a year: [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html).

```
public record Book ( String title , Year published ) {}
```

The implicit methods such as `equals` are implemented to consider each and every member field.

```
new Book( "Free To Choose" , Year.of( 1990 ) )
.equals( 
    new Book( "The Foundation Trilogy" , Year.of( 1974 ) ) 
)
```

> false

You can define a record locally, or nested or separately. Ditto for enum  and for interfaces, in Java 16 and later.

## `Set`

To collect objects while automatically eliminating duplicates, use a `Set` implementation.

```
Set< Book > books = new HashSet<>() ;
books.add( new Book( "Free To Choose" , Year.of( 1990 ) ) ) ;
books.add( new Book( "Free To Choose" , Year.of( 1990 ) ) ) ;  // Duplicate! Not added, because a set does not allow duplicates.
books.add( new Book( "The Foundation Trilogy" , Year.of( 1974 ) ) ) ;
```

[Interrogate for the size](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#size()). You’ll find a size of two rather than three.